# Hibernate - one-to-one mapping not working

Tags: java, hibernate

I followed a tutorial about one-to-one mapping in Hibernate but I always end up with `persistent class not known` exception.

The basic scenario is, that I have an order with reference to a customer and car. I would like to save this order together with the referenced entities into database.

Order.java:

```
public class Order implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 234543634;

    private String id;
    private Car car;
    private Customer customer;
    private Date date;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Car getCar() {
        return car;
    }

    public void setCar(Car car) {
        this.car = car;
    }

    public Customer getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
```

order.hbm.xml:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="wa2.entities.Order" table="ORDER">
        <id column="ID" name="id" type="java.lang.String" />
        <property column="DATE" name="date" type="java.util.Date" />
        <one-to-one name="car" class="wa2.entities.Car"
            cascade="save-update"></one-to-one>
        <one-to-one name="customer" class="wa2.entities.Customer"
            cascade="save-update"></one-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Any suggestion what am I missing here?

EDIT: car (it is abstract class but there are two more classes inheriting it)

```
public abstract class Car implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8513623981763963637L;

    private String name;
    private String id;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
```

Customer.java:

```
public class Customer implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 864235654;

    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String adress;
    private String id;
    private Company company;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getAdress() {
        return adress;
    }

    public void setAdress(String adress) {
        this.adress = adress;
    }

    public Company getCompany() {
        return company;
    }

    public void setCompany(Company company) {
        this.company = company;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your `Customer` and `Car` entities?

Comment: XML was necessary 10 years ago, when annotations didn't exist. For your own good, find another, more recent tutorial, that teaches how to use JPA annotations to define the mapping. You're learning obsolete stuff.

Comment: I edited the question and added the car and customer code

Answer (score 0):

Persistent class not known means that hibernate mapping does not know about the class you're trying to persist.

You should check the configuration (xml mappings in your case) and make sure that every class is mapped.

It's not enough to reference the class in `<one-to-one>` mapping. You should also map it as entity.

Comment: I have two classes extending Car (CityCar and Truck) and both are mapped in my hibernate.cfg.xml file. Since car is abstract, I dont think I have to map it, too, right?

Answer (score 0):

Please use annotation istead, it will be easier.
If not you need to List ALL the classes in your xml.
You need to defien iheritance strategy for the Cars.

Annotations are much simplier:
You need @Entity on top of your classes (apart from Car, see below).
You need @Id on id field.

For the inheritance, you have two option.

You can have Car annotatated as @MappedSuperclass which would mean it is not managed by JPA but its fields will be in inherited classes.

Or, more appropriate for your case, have Car anotated with @Entity and define inheritance strategy:
@Inheritance
@DiscriminatorColumn(...)